# how do i go ahead of this docker run command output

Tags: docker, docker-run

[image]

I am new to docker. trying to go throw this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dotnet-microservices/3-exercise-build-docker-image?ns-enrollment-type=LearningPath&ns-enrollment-id=learn.dotnet.create-microservices-with-dotnet). while running docker.

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5200:80 --name pizzabackendcontainer pizzabacken
```

I am getting the output in the image. what is the output suggest. i feel something wrong in the docker file

Comment: What's your expected result from your command lint? I saw you are doing container command line it is working

Comment: You can try to access `http://localhost:5200/pizzainfo` it might be work if you are doing the right thing from the document

Comment: http://localhost:5200/pizzainfo is not working

Comment: running the same command in the different tutorial started the container without the output in the picture above

Comment: You can try to use `docker run -itd -p 5200:80 --name pizzabackendcontainer-1 pizzabackend`

Comment: Had you build your image by this command `docker build -t pizzabackend .`?

Comment: yes it working docker run -itd -p 5200:80 --name pizzabackendcontainer-1 pizzabackend

Comment: Ok I see I  will write an answer & more detail for you

Comment: It's not impossible that `docker run` a container would dump a PNG file to stdout and exit.  What behavior do you actually expect?  If you think something is wrong with the Dockerfile, can you edit the question to include it?  In comments you suggest you should be running an HTTP server; is there further source code required for a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial guide us `docker run -it --rm -p 5200:80 --name pizzabackendcontainer pizzabackend`

- -it： That means you will execute the container by terminal mode.
- -rm： Automatically remove the container when it exits

So when you execute the command you will be interactive container command line and the container will be stopped when you exit.

```
docker run -itd -p 5200:80 --name pizzabackendcontainer-1 pizzabackend
```

If you want to run a container and keep it in your original terminal you can try to add `-d` parameter that will run the container in the background and print container ID.

more detail about docker run parameter you can refer [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)